# Cannot override onConfigurationChange in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, overriding

I'm trying to overload the funcion to detect an screen orientation change with the following code in a class that inherits from Fragment class.

```
  override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration?) {
        newConfig?.let { super.onConfigurationChanged(it) }
        if (newConfig != null) {
            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

                Handler().postDelayed({
                    otrosScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP)
                },600)

            } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

                Handler().postDelayed({
                    otrosScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP)
                },600)

            }
        }
    }
```

But it gives the error that onConfigurationChanged overrides nothing, so not sure how to handle the issue.

What could I do so a fragment reacts to the mentioned event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen when you update the sdk for a project and a function definition has changed. In this case, it looks like `onConfigurationChanged()` no longer accepts a nullable type.